# Why do we prefer primitives to boxed primitives in java

Tags: java

I was reading effective java 2nd edition and page number 23 says

```
// Hideously slow program! Can you spot the object creation
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Long sum = 0L;
    for(long i=0; i<=Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum)
}
```

Author says that the above code generates 2^31 object instantiations unnecessarily. Why does sum += i generate new Object? if I change the statement to

```
sum = sum + 1
```

not have this side effect?

Comment: Because they are immutable.

Comment: sum is a Long, so as @tkausl said, it is immutable. So sum += I keeps recreating new Long objects.

Comment: `sum = sum + 1` also has the same side effect. It will create a new boxed value each time it executes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying to rephrase what others have said in a clearer way:

The problem with `sum` is that **L**ong is a **reference** type; in other words, it is some sort of Object. Objects live on the heap; they are created (using "new" and a constructor) by the JVM, and "managed" by the garbage collector.

The auto-boxing feature allows you to use that reference-type Long variable the same way you would use a primitive-type long variable.

But a Long object is immutable; once created, its value can never change. But the whole loop is about constantly changing a value (by incrementing the counter)! So, to increment the counter, you have to fetch the value of the "current" Long object; add 1; and stuff that into the next Long object. Again, and again, ...

So, what your program is doing here is: creating **garbage** all the time. 
In other words: those Long objects are created; used once (to retrieve their value); and then they are "forgotten" (because no reference to them is kept anywhere). So they are immediately eligible for **garbage collection**.

Meaning: there are actually two impacts on performance here:

1. Unnecessary object creation [which is pretty cheap in Java, but still "more expensive" than simple calculations on a long value; the later probably being just one, two CPU instructions; whereas Object creation will lead to memory access and quite some CPU operations! ]
2. High-speed creation of objects that need to be garbage collected.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was not mentioned by author in the same section that Long is immutable which caused confusion to me.

Comment: Hint: all "big brother" reference types for primitive types like Integer, Double, ... are immutable. And that is actually a good thing! But one has to be aware of the consequences. Auto-boxing and those big brothers are often very helpful, but for example, when dealing with **a lot of numbers**, you might prefer a plain old int[] over an `ArrayList<Integer>` ... because of the significant overhead of the later construct. [ in case you need to worry about performance, so please don't take this as excuse for premature optimization!]

Comment: Note that the assignment operator `=` will **never** mutate an object. It will only set the reference.

Answer (score 5):

Due to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) as your variable `sum` is not a primitive type but of type `Long` (the wrapper class), `sum += i` will behind the scene create a new `Long` instance as it is an immutable class so it will somehow be equivalent to `sum = new Long(sum.longValue() + 1)`

Answer (score 3):

`sum = sum + 1` will still have same problem as `sum += 1` because `sum` on the right unboxes the value, then adds 1 to it, and finally creates a new `Long` object in order to box the result and assign the `sum` reference variable to point to the newly created object.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the `java.lang.Long` class is immutable. In other words, a new `Long` is created in each iteration of the loop instead of mutating the original in place. Compared to a primitive `long`, the boxed `Long` carries a lot of baggage. Your alternative statement, `sum = sum + 1` would have the same effect as the original code. Redeclaring `sum` as `long sum = 0L;` would instead create a new `long` on each iteration, which is *substantially* cheaper to create than a `Long`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `sum` is a `Long` datatype which is an immutable class in java.
In the statement  `sum += i;` ,you are trying to mutate(change) the value of `sum`.The java compiler automatically creates a new `Long` object during each iteration of the loop and then assign this newly created reference to `sum`.

> Hence, the writer of the book says `above code generates 2^31 object instantiations unnecessarily.`

Answer (score 2):

Because every time you sum, you create a new `Long` object.

`Long's` are immutable so you can't change the value, so at every iteration a new one is created with the sum.  If it were a primitive, then it would modify its current value.

Comment: Does `Long` have a method like `setValue` or so?

Comment: @MeikVtune [No.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) `Long` is immutable.